# Adding beforeSend function to XMLHttpRequest request

Tags: javascript, jquery, xmlhttprequest

I'm trying to add Ajax like `beforeSend` function to my `XMLHttpRequest`. I'm getting following error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of undefined

Here is my code:

```
var csrftoken = jQuery("[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]").val(); 

function csrfSafeMethod(method) {
    // these HTTP methods do not require CSRF protection
    return (/^(GET|HEAD|OPTIONS|TRACE)$/.test(method));
}

function beforeSend(xhr, settings) {
       if (!csrfSafeMethod(settings.type) && !this.crossDomain) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);
        }
   }

var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
http.open('POST', messageEndpoint, true);
http.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/json');
http.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (http.readyState === 4 && http.status === 200 && http.responseText) {
    Api.setResponsePayload(http.responseText);
  }
};

var params = JSON.stringify(payloadToWatson);
if (Object.getOwnPropertyNames(payloadToWatson).length !== 0) {
  Api.setRequestPayload(params);
}
 // Added beforeSend() function before sending the params
beforeSend();
http.send(params);
```

Comment: It feels like you are mixing up Jquery and regular vanilla JS? If you are using Jquery, you specify the `beforeSend` as a property to an $.ajax call. But if you are not, you cannot call the `beforeSend` in the way you set it up. Notice you are specifying two arguments there. But when you call it like that...where are the arguments? So the first question is whether you intend to use Jquery here?

Answer (score 0):

I notice your using jQuery... then you can use `$ajax` method; here an example

```
$ajax({
    url: 'yourURLhere',
    data: {some: 'value'},//{} or [] or ""
    method: 'POST',
    beforeSend: function(jqXHR, settings) {
        // do something
    },
    success: function(data) {

    },
    error: function(err) {

    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Anyone who was in my situation and trying to send csrf token with XMLHttpRequest request. Here is how I solved it:

Create csrf token:

```
var csrfcookie = function() {
    var cookieValue = null,
        name = 'csrftoken';
    if (document.cookie && document.cookie !== '') {
        var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
        for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
            var cookie = cookies[i].trim();
            if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) == (name + '=')) {
                cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return cookieValue;
};
```

Build http request:

```
var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
http.open('POST', messageEndpoint, true);
http.setRequestHeader('X-CSRFToken', csrfcookie());
```